# Saving keras models with shared layers

Tags: keras

I have two keras models with shared layers, whose weights I want to save in hd5 files. If I save both models individually, I think the shared layers are saved twice using the double of space in disk. How can I save it in a unique file?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the shared layers and put them in a separate model. For example, if the shared layers are: `layer1` and `layer2`, then you will have to create a model where the input layer is `layer1` and the output layer is `layer2`. The output of `layer2` will be the input to both models.

If the shared layers are the first layers in both models, then the task becomes easier and you will have three models after separating the shared layers. If the layers are between the input and the output layer of each model, then you will have to separate the layers before the shared layers in each model as well which will result in two additional models.

To achieve this easily, you can use the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) to combine multiple models by taking the output of one model as an input to another. For example, if you have the models `shared_model`, `model1` and `model2`, then you can create the two models for training or inference by taking the output of `shared_model` as an input for `model1` and `model2`:

```py
input_layer = Input(input_shape)
shared_output = shared_model(input_layer)

combined_output1 = model1(shared_output)
combined_model1 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=combined_output1)

combined_output2 = model2(shared_output)
combined_model2 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=combined_output2)
```

This way you can train `combined_model1` or `combined_model2` or use them for inference.

To be able to save checkpoints for the models `shared_model` and `model1` while training `combined_model1`, you can use the [alt-model-checkpoint](https://pypi.org/project/alt-model-checkpoint/) library to create a callback.